# VBA Word Macro doesnt recognize whitespaces or wildcards

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a VBA Word Macro that gets words from .txt list and color highlight them in a word .doc document.

The problem is that the script ignores whitespaces and wildcards from the .txt list. I insert the word "wit" but it also changes words like witHIN , witCHE, etc.

I tried inserting wildcards in the .txt file, like  or using white spaces like " wit ", but it didnt worked. The script ignore the whitespaces and the wildcards.

**THE CODE IS HERE: http://pastebin.com/m3e20f932**

Melissa.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the code, BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to add the option `.matchWholeWord = True` to line 233? If you would rather do it by using whitespace, you could remove the `Trim` on line 63. If you want to use wildcards, you would need to have `.MatchWildcards = True` on line 233.

Comment: Kinopiko i tried removing the TRIM and also worked, thanks.

But when i tried adding .MatchWildcards = True, and then went to the txt file and inserted <wit> it worked, but instead of replacing every wit word for wit, replaced with <wit>. Why that happened ?

Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding the `MatchWholeWord:=True` property to your `Execute` statement.

It's untested, but I believe that will give you the results you want.